# Setting radgrid page numbers programmatically and assiging varying sized set of data to each page

Tags: paging, guid, radgrid

Afternoon folks.

I am using a radgrid as this has lots of functionality that I wish to keep (exporting, line selection, scrolling, etc) but I have come across a request I'm not sure how to handle and as such, I'd like some advice!

I have a radgrid attached to an object datasource implementing a SelectMethod  of GetProductList and a SelectCountMethod of CountProductItems.This would return something along the lines of:

[image]

With CountProductItems returning 9.

What I need to do with this is dynamically set the radgrid so that the paging is defined by the guid i.e. one page for each guid present.

So in the above example, we'd have 3 pages.

On page load you'd be shown Page 1:

[image]

With the pager items displaying 1, 2, 3.

Click on page 2 and you'd see:

[image]

and clicking on page 3:

[image]

Does that makes sense? Is it possible and if so, any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible with paging. However I think it is very possible to set up some buttons with custom queries depending on the "page" they are on.  So a "<" and ">" button underneath the grid.  I implemented something similar to this a while ago for a project depending on their member groups, and queried using Linq.